# Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j: trove4j: 20160824

Tags: libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build libGDX project for Android via Gradle. 
I get following error: **Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j: trove4j: 20160824.**

I have tried every combination of:

```
jCenter(), mavenLocal(), mavenCentral(), google()
```

In my build.gradle files, root and android's one.

Also tried different orders of it, as suggested by others in other forums.
What sould I do?

**Full error:**

```
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':android:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/media/mruser/Data/AndroidSDK/extras/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    - file:/media/mruser/Data/AndroidSDK/extras/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    - file:/media/mruser/Data/AndroidSDK/extras/google/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    - file:/media/mruser/Data/AndroidSDK/extras/google/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    - file:/media/mruser/Data/AndroidSDK/extras/android/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    - file:/media/mruser/Data/AndroidSDK/extras/android/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    - file:/home/mruser/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    - file:/home/mruser/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    - file:/home/mruser/GDX/ColorGame/libs/trove4j-20160824.jar
    - file:/home/mruser/GDX/ColorGame/libs/trove4j.jar
  Required by:
      project :android
```

Root build.gradle:

```
   buildscript {
        repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "ColorfulGame"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        flatDir {
            dir rootProject.file( 'libs' )
        }

    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}


project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

        compile group: 'org.jetbrains.trove4j', name: 'trove4j', version: '20160824'
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

    }
}


project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    compile files("libs/SGDX.jar")
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Android build.gradle:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sk.ap.cg"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'sk.ap.cg/sk.ap.cg.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why two version of `android gradle plugin` artifact ??

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you specify it?

Comment: Look at root gradle file, inside buildscript dependency tag you've inject two version of one artifact. And second thing is that why you've buildscript tag inside build.gradle of android module

Comment: @Aryan
I have updated the build files. Now I can run desktop project and even rundadroid app via Android Studio emulator, but when I run assemble task I get same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was asociated with *mavenCentral()* and *mavenLocal()*.

***allproject*** and ***buildfile*** closures in root buildfile should look like this:

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
}
```

Comment: We need a new solution since jcenter is being deprecated and this lib doesn't exist on mavenCentral...

Comment: @June, yes, it exists in https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/, which requires login and password.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still looks for solution and mavens are ok - in my case problem was with outdated react-native-document-picker library. I installed last version and problem has gone. So be sure problem is not caused by your libraries.